# Is the crypto-key pair in IPv6 SeND persistent?

Tags: cryptography, ipv6

IPv6 introduces the `NDP` extension `SeND` to help mitigate identity theft, however, is the **non-PKI** public/private key pair used during the process persistent to some degree, or generated on every connection with the router?

[RFC3972](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3972#section-4) hints at a possible persistent key combination:

> One optimization is particularly important.  **If the subnet prefix of
>
> the address changes but the address owner's public key does not**, the
> old modifier value MAY be reused.  If it is reused, the algorithm
> SHOULD be started from step 4.  This optimization avoids repeating
> the expensive search for an acceptable modifier value but may, in
> some situations, make it easier for an observer to link two addresses
> to each other.

This isn't very concrete however, stating only a case where it *might* happen.